# Manually determine the last thing PHP does before it renders a page?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out the best way to unset a php session variable, after all pages have loaded and the page will be rendered to the browser. I have a page that includes & requires several pages to be rendered. I want to know if there is a built in php function that will tell php to do something right before the page is completed. Or what would the best way/practice to do this?

EDIT##
Here's what I added...

```
function unsetHIST_ID(){unset($_SESSION['Hist_CID']);}
register_shutdown_function('unsetHIST_ID');
```

Comment: auto_append_file php.ini setting?

Comment: I only need this for one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure why you want this but if you want a function to be executed after script `execution finishes` or `exit()` is called then you should look at [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

Example

```
function shutdown() {
    echo "Am dead anyway";
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

echo "<pre>";
echo "Hello am Alive",PHP_EOL;
```

Output

```
Hello am Alive
Am dead anyway <---------------This would always run last
```

Comment: Seee .. How are your pages included ??? It you call exit anyway .. it would trigger this function

Answer (score 1):

There's the .ini directive [auto_append_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file), which is parsed last by PHP if specified. It's basically treated as if you'd put `require('somefile.php')` as the very last command in a file yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like

```
register_shutdown_function ('my_atexit_function');
```

or maybe you can do this with

```
ob_start('content_handler');
```

The first function will be called immediately before exiting, which is not exactly what you asked for; and the second just before output, but that allows you to do something with an output that's already made static.

I'd go with `register_shutdown_function` though.